# Create TFS 2010 Collection from existing database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, tfs

I have a backup of TFS Project collection database. I want to restore it. I tried creating a project collection with same name and then restoring the database but it didn't work. I also tried changing instance id from db's extended properties.

I guess there should be a way to restore a project collection or all my one year of work is lost :)

I'm using TFS 2010 and SQL Server 2008 R2

Thanks

P.S. I have a fresh installation of TFS 2010. The project collection backup is from another machine.

P.P.S. I don't have the configuration database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869.aspx)? It may help.

(However, if you are missing a database from the full set, it may be significantly harder to restore your data).

Comment: There's said to backup Tfs_Configuration db. I don't have that database. I want to restore the collection database without old Tfs_Configuration...

Comment: You may have trouble. However, searching on TFS_Configuration threw up hits like this, which may(?) help you rebuild that db: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfssetup/thread/d949edf3-1795-448a-a1cc-39555ce87b50#e8beddac-5aae-4dd9-98f8-f043376bf365

Comment: Good, Jason you just saved me from killing myself :) I wish I could vote up thousand times your answer. Thanks, you don't know how greatfull I'm :-)

Comment: Glad I could help. I've been there with TFS too - it can seem like there's no solution sometimes, until you find that crucial snippet of info... :-)